# How appropriate is to use 'Nice to e-meet you'

Tags: meaning-in-context, email, conversation

I work in a software organization so email conversations are frequent. Recently one client e-mailed me with "**Nice to e-meet you**". I want to know how appropriate is it to use 'Nice to **e-meet** you'. Is it formal English or not? Can I use it in conversation with potential clients?

Comment: On an informal basis, I think it is a nice expression.

Comment: Formal or informal it is the most honest way to say "nice to meet you". If its online, you're not really meeting them, you're e(lectronically)-meeting them. It should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me to be merely a humorous and friendly twist on the conventional formula "Nice to meet you". It sounds quite harmless to me.

However, I don't think you could use it in *face-to-face* conversation, because it depends on email communication for a context that gives it relevance.